# Questions about C++ operators overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am a beginner of C++ learning, and I have some questions about the '<<' and '>>'.
Why the results of cout are not correct? At the same time, after I input the coordinate of c, the program froze.
Code:

```
class Vector
{friend istream &operator >> (istream &is,Vector &vec );
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &os,Vector &vec );
private:
    int num;
    double *cor;
public:
    Vector(int n=0,double *c=NULL);//
};
int main()
{   double b[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    Vector a(5,b);
    cout<<a;
    Vector c(2);
    cin>>c;
}
Vector::Vector(int n,double *c)
{
    num=n;
    double *cor=new double[num];
    if (c) {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {cor[i]=c[i];cout<<cor[i]<<endl;}
    }
}
istream &operator >> (istream &is,Vector &vec )
{   cout<<"Input the coordinate：";
    for (int i=0;i<vec.num;i++)
        is>>vec.cor[i];
    return is;
}
ostream &operator << (ostream &os,Vector &vec )
{
    for (int i=0;i<vec.num;i++){
        os<<vec.cor[i];}
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: the streaming operators normally don't interact with the user. Your implementation would print a message even if it was reading from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double *cor=new double[num];
```

You're declaring a local variable named `cor`, not initializing the member `cor`. It should be:

```
cor = new double[num];
```

---

However in real code, you would use an [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to a `double` array, which  `delete`s the array automatically (with no additional overhead):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // for unique_ptr

using namespace std;

class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int = 0, double* = nullptr);

private:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Vector& vec);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Vector& vec);

    int num;
    unique_ptr<double[]> array;
};

int main() {
    double b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Vector a(5, b);
    cout << a;

    Vector c(2);
    cin >> c;
}

Vector::Vector(int n, double* c) {
    num = n;
    array = make_unique<double[]>(n); // in C++14
    //array = unique_ptr<double[]>(new double[n]); // in C++11

    if (!c) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = c[i];
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Vector& vec) {
    cout << "Input the coordinates: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.num; i++)
        is >> vec.array[i];
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Vector& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.num; i++)
        os << vec.array[i];
    return os;
}
```

Comment: There is also memory leak in OP's code. He hasn't defined destructor.

Comment: Yes. Even with a destructor the default copy/move constructors would cause double-deletes. The correct way is to drop the `new`/`delete` nonsense, and use `unique_ptr<double[]>`.

Comment: Never heard of it. How to use the unique_ptr thing?@tuple_cat

Comment: After I defined the destructor , a local Vector variable in reloading `Vector operator +` was deleted before return .How to correct it?@tuple_cat

Comment: Sounds like another question.

Answer (score 0):

Small but important tip:
using 'const':

```
> ostream &operator << (ostream &os,const Vector &vec)
```

since vec is received by reference and you are not going to change it.